# PayPal custom button with dynamic price

Tags: forms, dynamic, input, paypal, payment

I have a website that offers a service where the price changes dynamically. For instance there are radio buttons and checkboxes that make the final price variate. At the final stage I have an hidden input that contains the final price.
How do I tell PayPal that that is the price to charge? I have tried to follow the documentations on PayPal website but I can't find an answer for this.

How could I dynamically change the values of these inputs but also make sure it's safe?

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

<!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="herschelgomez@xyzzyu.com">

<!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">

<!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Hot Sauce-12 oz. Bottle">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="5.95">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

<!-- Prompt buyers to enter their desired quantities. -->
<input type="hidden" name="undefined_quantity" value="1">

<!-- Display the payment button. -->
<input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif"
alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
<img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1"
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >

</form>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I'm really stuck on this.
Thanks,
Jeff